# Fullcalendar with resources won't start on monday

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

For some reason, our Fullcalendar with resources does not want to start on monday, it always starts on the current day that we are. According to the docs, we should use [firstDay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay), it also states that :

> If weekNumberCalculation is set to 'ISO', this option defaults to 1 (Monday).

Which we did in our case, but no changes. We also tried upgrading to a different version (all above 5) but to no avail.
We are using version v5.11.3 of Fullcalendar (premium).
Anyone that can point us in the right direction?

In the screenshot that I've added, you can see it start on today (friday 18/11/2022).

[image: Current situation]

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar2');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'xxx',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
    hiddenDays: [0, 6],
    locale: 'nl-be',
    weekNumberCalculation: "ISO",
    droppable: true,
    eventStartEditable: false,
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    views: {
        resourceTimelineWeek: {
            duration: {days: 7},
            slotDuration: '24:00:00',
            buttonText: "Week",

        },
        resourceTimelineDay: {
            duration: {days: 1},
            slotDuration: '24:00:00',
            buttonText: "Dag"
        }
    },
    editable: true,
    events: {
        url: 'xxx.php',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    },        
    refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
    resources: {
        url: 'xxx.php',
        type: 'POST',            
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }

    }, eventReceive: function (info) {
        var resourceid = info.event._def.resourceIds[0];
        var date = info.event._instance.range.start.toLocaleString();
        var employeeid = info.draggedEl.dataset.employeeid;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "xxx.php",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'resourceid': resourceid,
                'date': date,
                'employeeid': employeeid
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var response = eval(data);
                
                info.revert();

                if (response.success) {
                    refetch();
                } 
            }
        });
    }, eventContent: function (arg) {
        let divEl = document.createElement('div');
        let htmlTitle = arg.event._def.extendedProps.html;
        divEl.innerHTML = htmlTitle;

        let arrayOfDomNodes = [divEl];
        return {domNodes: arrayOfDomNodes}

    }
});

calendar.render();

function refetch() {
    //direct refetch doesn't work
    calendar.refetchEvents();
}
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/firstDay sets what day is considered the first day of a week, for internationalisation purposes. It has nothing to do with the date on which the calendar initialises. I think you misunderstood the documentation

Comment: @ADyson Do you mean that it is meant to set the startday of the week (internally)? And not to let the view start on the current day? Is there an option to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: `it is meant to set the startday of the week (internally)`...yes, in order to account for different cultural conventions in different parts of the world. It will then affect (amongst other things) the day of the week shown on the left-hand side in the month view (demo  1 (default): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBbMJRv, demo 2 (with firstDay changed): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdKXdQe .

Comment: Anyway, you possibly want [`initialDate`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate). Note that, in a "week" view, this will cause the calendar to start on the first day of the week containing the date specified. Similarly in a "month" view it'll show the beginning of the relevant month. But for "day" views, it'll start directly on the specified date. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/poKaoQp .

Comment: N.B. My demo uses a hard-coded date, but there is nothing to prevent you from calculating one using JavaScript and passing that to the calendar.

Comment: However, if you _do_ just want the calendar to start on the nearest Monday to the current date, then `firstDay` should do that for you, it's unclear why it wasn't working in your case (you didn't actually show us any code where you tried to use it!). Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOKZOgY

Comment: We tried firstDay multiple times, but it just did not work. I didn't add it to the code because I thought mentioning we used it would be enough. Now firstday didn't do the trick for us, so we used the initialDate like you suggested and build a little custom code to set it to the right date with gotoDate. Thank you for pointing us in the right direction. Feel free to make an answer, if not I'll make one by the end of the week.

Comment: It's still unclear why firstDay doesn't work for you - it should. If you can provide a [mre] of the issue we can perhaps find out what's going wrong